# Delete Multiselection rows of a dbgrid

Tags: delphi, ado

Hello I need ur help for Deleting a number of rows in a dbgrid
first my database is access and  the error of deleting is "insufficient key conlumn information for updating or refreshin"

and adoquery related with dbgrid is:

SELECT tblMessages.*, tblMessages.Direction, tblContacts.Name
FROM tblMessages LEFT JOIN tblContacts ON tblMessages.MobileNumber = tblContacts.MobileNum
WHERE (((tblMessages.Direction)=1))

and method of delting is : adoquery1.delete;

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to dbGrid, it is your dataset (adoQuery1) which does the action. dbGrid just visualizes your dataset records.

Make sure all your tables have primary key fields. I guess you should also include primary keys of both joined tables in the SELECT statement too.

There is a known bug in Microsoft ADO which I am not sure if it is fixed in the latest version or not; that is:

[BUG: Problem Updating ADO Hierarchical Recordset When Join Tables Share Same Column Name](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246905)

It says, if the primary key in one table has the same name as one of the fields in the other table, and the tables are joined together, then you may get that "*Insufficient key column information for updating or refreshing.* " error.

BTW, In your SELECT statement, you already have tblMessages.*, why are you including tblMessages.Directions too?

Comment: dear , this error didnot occure in joining thats apear in deleting by method adoqurey1.delete;

Comment: I know it occurs while deleting a record. When you delete a record, DELETE statement has to find the record in the recordset. Obviously it does not have enough info about the record which is supposed to be deleted. I told you that ADO has a bug which causes this, and that error occurs while deleting a record. So you should check what I mentioned in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

"insufficient key conlumn information for updating or refreshin"
This error means that you are refreshing your DBGRID or dataquery after you deleted your record you can simply do this

```
 var
  sql_String;
begin
 sql_:'DELETE * FROM [yourTableName] WHERE [id] = '+DBGRID.Fields[0].AsInteger; // OR whichever Fielnumber that stores id (PrimaryKey) of the table
 AdoQuery1.Active:= False;
 AdoQuery1.SQL.Clear;
 AdoQuery1.SQL.Add(sql_);
 AdoQuery1.ExecSQL;
 // to refresh your data you have to deactive and active the data that is showing your data in the query
 MainData.Active:= False;
 MainData.Active:= True;
end;
```